# Type mismatch with operation on lists

Tags: ocaml

New in Ocaml and I'm trying to implement a couple of functions to manage a list of a custom types.

I'm trying to manage a list of types, and when I need to add a new element to the list I need to make some checks.
This is my actual code:

```
open Ast
open Easy_logging
exception DuplicateEntry

let logger = Logging.make_logger "SymbolTable" Debug [Cli Debug]

type variable = {
  id: string;
  tipe: Ast.typ
}

type dec = {
  variables: variable list;
  parent: dec option
}

let begin_block table =
  if List.length table > 1 then
     let last_scope = List.nth table ((List.length table) -1) in
     let new_scope = {variables=[]; parent=last_scope} in
     new_scope::table
  else {variables=[]; parent=None}::table

let add_entry symbol info table =
  let tail_scope = List.nth table ((List.length table) - 1) in
  {id=symbol; tipe=info}::tail_scope.variables;
  logger#debug "Added inside the table the node with id %s" symbol

let rec lookup symbol table = failwith "lookup: Not implemented yet"
```

I'm trying to implement the operation begin_block but I'm getting the following error:

```
File "src/symbol_table.ml", line 31, characters 16-21:
31 |      new_scope::table
                     ^^^^^
Error: This expression has type dec option list
       but an expression was expected of type dec list
       Type dec option is not compatible with type dec 
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 26 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:01.
```

In this case, the table is the list
I'm losing somethings but at the moment I'm not able to find the error :/, maybe this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're omitting a lot of context here, and I had to remove references to missing modules in order to reproduce, which means I've made several assumptions that may be wrong.

Given that, my guess is that you've copied code that originally used the Base or Core standard library replacement, where the `List.nth` function returns an `'a option`, as opposed to the standard OCaml implementation which will raise an exception instead if the given index is out of bounds.

The reason I think so is that the `parent` field of `dec` has type `dec option` and is assigned `last_scope` directly, which means `last_scope` must have the same type. And if `List.nth` has type `'a list -> int -> 'a`, then `'a` must have type `dec option`, which means `table` must have type `dec option list`. And you can't prepend a `dec` to a `dec option list`, hence the error.

Lastly, a good way to find the cause of issues like this is to make your assumptions explicit by annotating the type of variables. For example, annotating the type of `table` here will give you a different error, narrowing it down `last_scope` having the type `dec` but being expected to have type `dec option` when being assigned to `parent`.

Comment: Sorry if I omitted some context, but I need to make some other questions about this. the option type is inside the type *dec* and the table should have a type *dec*, right? and the item inside the list can have an option parent. Why my list needs to have a dec option list type instant of dec list type?

Comment: By my understanding, `table` should be `dec list` and `parent` should be `dec option`. The easiest fix then is to use `List.nth_opt` instead of `List.nth`.

Comment: Your intuition about the code is correct, but unfortunately also with `List.ntg_opt` I receive the same error :(

Comment: Then I've probably made some incorrect assumption because of the missing context. If you want accurate advice you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: I correct my previous answer, yes the problem was resolved with List.nth_opt, thanks and sorry my stupid question. But I'm new with this new paradigm :) I will learn